# unable to find javac compiler from an executable jar

Tags: java, ant

I am working on a simple java editor that uses **ant** to call **JDK**.

On eclipse everything work fine,  I am able to build **build.xml**. The problems is when I export my Editor to an **executable jar**, and I try to build the **build.xml** of a project, I get the famous problems:

```
Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
```

Important:

If i run my **jar Editor**  from **cmd** it's work fine ,but if i double click the **Editor** jar it doesn't work , i get the famous problem (unable to find javac  compiler...).

Notice:

1. JAVA_HOME  points to the **JDK**.
2. I am using **ant.jar** and **ant-launcher.jar**.
3. Eclipse  points to my **JDK** installation.
4. **tools.jar** is added to JDK/lib folder

Comment: "Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK." - It looks like your JAVA_HOME points to a JRE installation instead of a JDK. The JRE does not come with javac and other development tools. Change your JAVA_HOME environment variable, restart eclipse, and you should be good.

Comment: An "executable JAR" is a JAR file that includes your classes, the necessary JDK classes, and the JVM.  It does not include the Java compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to set `fork` attribute to yes on `javac` target .

Comment: It worked for me. Could you please explain the problem and how fork helped?

Answer (score 1):

Your JAVA_HOME looks like it is pointing to a JRE installation, not a JDK installation.  (The error message says it is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"`!)

A JRE does not include any of the Java development tools ... such as the `javac` Java compiler that Ant is trying to load / use.

If you really have a JDK installation on your machine, then all you need to do is to change the JAVA_HOME environment variable so that it refers to it ... instead of the JRE.  Otherwise, you *also* need to download and install the relevant JRE.

Comment: @oussama.elhadri Why is it named `jre7` then?

Comment: i don't know , but my JAVA_HOME points to **C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/**  , when i do the same thing on eclipse everything work

Comment: @oussama.elhadri - That's not what the error message says!  You need to pay attention to the evidence rather than denying it.

Comment: i think the problem is My **jar** it's not able to find **javac compilar** as **Eclipse** do . beceause with the same configuration **Eclipse** build correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the **JDK**.

JAVA_HOME is currently set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\ **jre7**

The message is fairly informative and to the point, is it not?